# Any reason why local spacetime translation invariance sources perturbations that breaks global spacetime translation invariance?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, energy-conservation, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In general relativity (GR), metric perturbations are sourced by the energy-momentum tensor. Given that energy and momentum are defined as the scalar and vector quantity conserved by time and spatial translation symmetry, respectively, then those very metric perturbations that are sourced by the energy-momentum tensor mean that we must be careful when defining just what energy and momentum we are talking about. At any given point the (0,0) entry for example is the energy density as it would be defined on a manifold tangent to that point, given that space-time could very well be curved at that point, preventing us from otherwise defining what we even call energy. Hence why energy and momentum are local and not global quantities in GR. There's nothing particularly complex going on here, but it does mean that we get to say this:

Energy and momentum are locally conserved quantities that source perturbations that break the very symmetries that would have defined those quantities globally.

Or put another way:

Local space and time translation invariance defines quantities that source perturbations that break global space and time translation invariance.

Is there something profound going on here or is this just a cute coincidence? Does anything else even come close to doing something like this? Am I the only one that finds it odd that the universe is made up of local quantities that source the very perturbations that disallow a global version of such quantities?

Comment: Maybe I am just slow today, but I don't understand what you are asking. There is no need for a source in the local picture. Gravitational waves carry both energy and momentum. This is no different from any other wave theory. Do waves break a global symmetry? Of course. Is that profound? No, I don't think so. But that is really a question about opinion, not a question about physics, isn't it? That the universe is "merely local" is false, by the way, and not just in general relativity. The effective existence of "infinity" is absolutely crucial for the structure of the universe.

Comment: You've really misunderstood the question. I'm asking about the apparent coincidence that local energy momentum create metric perturbations which in turn make it impossible to define global energy momentum. So local energy momentum creates metric perturbations which in turn invalidate the notion of global energy momentum. Is this just a coincidence ?

Comment: I am not even sure that the notion of global energy momentum conservation is false because of local perturbations. There was a similar question yesterday "Nonlocal Gravitational energy: How to localize nontrivial topology in GR?" and I pointed to this article: "Conserved quantities in general relativity -- the view from null infinity"
Po-Ning Chen, Mu-Tao Wang, Ye-Kai Wang, Shing-Tung Yau. It is complicated but I have a feeling that it probably does not work in the way you imagine.

Comment: It absolutely is. There are fairly simple cases (in cosmology for example) where energy is not conserved as a result of the metric being dynamic. More generally it just directly follows that a dynamic metric breaks space and time translation invariance, so by definition energy and momentum no longer have meaning, let alone being conserved.

Comment: The cosmological case of non-conservation of energy is not caused by local objects. Gravitationally bound local objects in a universe with constant Hubble constant are indeed conserving the local energy in the volume of their gravitational influence (up to gravitational waves), so they are doing exactly the opposite of what you are claiming.

Comment: I never claimed that local energy is not conserved. Global energy is an ill defined concept when the metric is not flat. This is my only point. My question relates to the fact that the metric is made non flat precisely by perturbations sourced by the local energy momentum density.

Comment: See the citation for the question what energy means in non-flat spacetime. The phenomenology and the theory clearly indicates that energy in gravitationally bound systems is not lost to simple spatial expansion, even if it is lost due to many-body instabilities gravitational waves. The perturbations are actually stabilizing against Hubble flow. In addition, the metric of a constantly expanding universe can be perfectly flat on large scales and you seem to be mixing up things that have nothing to do with each other for all I can tell.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding my question. I'm perfectly fine with the meaning of energy in any context. I'm talking about what I find to be a peculiar coincidence regarding that meaning.

Comment: I agree. We are having a language problem here. Maybe you should rewrite your question so that we can all understand what it is that you are asking.

Comment: "Local space and time translation invariance defines quantities that source perturbations that break global space and time translation invariance." it would help if you fleshed out what exactly you mean by this statement, because as it stands, it either seems untrue or vacuous?